# Java find not so specific String

Tags: java, string, find

I have product description, furniture, many words and I need to find the size (dimensions) of the product. The problem is, the format of the description of the size is not always the same. Only one thing stays same : letter "x" between the numbers, and if there is "x" in the text and another "x" just a few chars away, it is for sure the size description.

Possible formats of size description /all of them appears/:
size:110x76x60 cm   /without spaces/
size: 150 x 64,5 x 200 cm  /with spaces/
Size: l90 x h55 x w60 cm   /as length, height, width/
Size: 149 x v110 x h40  /only some numbers have letters before them/

And not to mention, the numbers dont have to be 3 digits, they can be only 2 digits. 
 But if it is easier to do it for only one type of format, I take it :) and I let the program check the whole list for all the possible formats again and again.

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried so far?

Sounds like a perfect job for a `regular expression`

JavaDocs have a wealth of information on `regular expressions` and how to implement them in java code here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: So far I have no idea. :) So far my only suggestion is to look for the string "size:", but that brings me nowhere, when I have no clue when to stop parsing the text - the size description don't ends always with "cm".

Comment: Andreas, holy cow :) looks interesting, I will study it, so far I have no idea whats going on. :)

Comment: A possible pattern in Java: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\d,]{2,4})[\\s]?[\\w]?x[\\s]?[\\w]?([\\d,]{2,4})[\\s]?[\\w]?x[\\s]?[\\w]?([\\d,]{2,4})");

Answer (score 1):

I'm not proud of it, but it works and should give you an idea for making it recursive. It will also allow you to NOT learn regex, which not everyone wants to learn:

This code works and will get you the sizes you are looking for:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int l;
        int h;
        int w;

        String text = "Size: l90 x h55 x w60";
        String text2 = text.replaceAll("\\D+"," ").trim();
        System.out.println(text2);
        String[] sizes = text2.split(" ");

        l = Integer.valueOf(sizes[0]);
        h = Integer.valueOf(sizes[1]);
        w = Integer.valueOf(sizes[2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Matcher` and a regular expression.

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\d+(?:,\d+)?) *x *[a-zA-Z]*(\d+(?:,\d+)?) *x *[a-zA-Z]*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)").matcher(productDescription);
while (matcher.find()) {
  String number1 = matcher.group(1);
  String number2 = matcher.group(2);
  String number3 = matcher.group(3);
}
```

Comment: Won't match `64,5`.

Comment: If you use the `(?:x)` [*non-capturing* group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special), you don't have to skip indexes when calling `group()`.